# how added new Condition (if) wordpress costum field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have this code to display the custom field in WordPress

```
if( isset($digi) && !empty($digi) )
```

Now we want to add a new condition (check in terms of being categorized)
That's how we did it

```
if( isset(product_categories=55,56,57,58) || isset($digi) && !empty($digi) )
```

Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do - but I know that you are missing a ```'```.
And no, isset with a hardcoded string makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in what file or loop you perform this code, but your solution might be something similair to this:

```
$your_category = "THE CATEGORY YOU WANT TO CHECK FOR";
$product_categories = array(55,56,57,58);
if( in_array($your_categroy, $product_categories) || ( isset($digi) && !empty($digi) ) )
```